# Batman vs. Maxwell Smart. Who said, "Good thinking, ...!" first?

Tags: etymology, american-english, catch-phrases

Recently, I've come across the catchphrase, "*Good thinking, [name/noun]!"* three times on ELU. 
The first was in a question referring to Terry Pratchett's catchphrase "**Good thinking, that man!**" [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189942/good-thinking-that-man)

The second was [FumbleFinger's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189951/44619) answer where he affirms that the former is a homage to the popular American catchphrase, **Good thinking, Batman!** Made famous in the American TV cult series, *Batman*.

The third, I happily stumbled upon myself and posted in  [“Definite ninety-nine” - UK English meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193773/44619). The catchphrase is taken from an American spy sitcom, called *Get Smart* about two secret agents; Maxwell Smart, Agent 86, and his beautiful and intelligent female partner, Agent 99. The series, devised by Mel Brooks and Buck Henry, was responsible for coining a multitude of catchphrases, one of which was:    **Good thinking, 99!**

### Data

*[**Get Smart**](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Get_Smart)* was broadcast between 1965–1970 but despite my cursory attempts, I couldn't pinpoint the year the catchphrase was actually launched.

*[**Batman**](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Batman_(TV_series)#The_Penguin.27s_Nest_.5B2.27.5D)* appeared on television screens a year later and ended its run in 1968. According to Wikiquote the phrase **Good thinking, Robin!** was used in season two, episode 27.  (At least that's my understanding)

Established the fact the catchphrase, "**Good thinking!**" originated in the US, and its popularity became worldwide thanks to the exportation of American TV shows in the 60s and 70s. I would like to know:

- Who said it first, *Batman* or *Maxwell Smart*?
- Was there an earlier TV or radio show with the formulaic catchphrase: Good thinking, + (name)+! anytime in the mid/late 50s?
- Finally, what about Australia? Were either of the catchphrases popular during the 60s? I also recall reading on the Internet that *Good thinking, 99!* is still being used there. Is that true?

Comment: Three downvotes. *Why*??? I've shown research. It's clear. It's debatable whether it's useful, but I sincerely would like to know which catchphrase came first. It's not off topic, the answer can't be easily found in any dictionary, it's not opinion-based, it's not too broad...

Comment: I agree. I upvoted.

Comment: Thank you for the 4 upvotes which have cancelled the 3 downvotes. I'd still like to know the motivation lying behind the first 3 negative votes though. And talk about "slow day" (37 views in twelve hours!) I suppose  people must have lives outside ELU :)

Comment: +1 We really need to encourage *whys* on downvotes. Also, *Good thinking, Max* is also cited as a repeated line in the series by [imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058805/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: this question comes up in the "Related" sidebar for the "If we have a 'second' of time, what's 'first'?" question, which in turn has been showing up on the "Hot Network Questions" list.

Comment: Can confirm "Good thinking 99" is still used frequently in Australia - I think because we're so far behind that Get Smart is seen as a new release tv show here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Batman

According to [this wikiquote page](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Batman_(TV_series)#The_Penguin.27s_Nest_.5B2.27.5D):

> Batman: Good thinking, Robin.
>   -- "The Penguin's Nest", first aired December 7, 1966 ([Wikipedia, season 2, number 61](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Batman_television_episodes#Season_2:_1966.E2.80.9367)).

So Batman is 7th December, 1966.

Having searched through scripts + quotes of all the series, I couldn't see it, however this answer (Yahoo! answers) says:

> "When batman gets a riddle from the riddler, he just says the riddle loud out and changes it into something completely random like from blueberry muffins to kitchen equiptment. (true story)
>   When batman solves the riddle Robin always goes *"Good thinking batman!"*."

That gave me the episode *"A Riddle a Day Keeps the Riddler Away"*, from 16 Feb. 1966. However, I haven't checked if it actually does have it in by watching (no sound).

---

Maxwell Smart

> "Good idea, 99" appeared in the episode "KAOS in Control".
>   -- [atomicmpc.com](http://forums.atomicmpc.com.au/index.php/topic/16401-good-thinking-99/)

But that isn't quite it.

I can say that it appeared in the show "Perils in a Pet Shop" - season 2 episode 13.

([Script from springfieldspringfield.co.uk](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=get-smart-1965&episode=s02e13), then [date from imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0587547/)).

That was aired, no kidding, 10 Dec. 1966 - 3 days later than it first appeared in Batman.

So Batman / Robin said it first as far as I can tell. It is not well known which episodes it was said by Maxwell Smart - I can make no guarantees that the episode stated above was the first occurrence.

---

Other, earlier uses

There was a series called *"[The Many Loves of Dobie Gillis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052490/?ref_=tt_ov_inf):"*, and in [Season 2, Episode 3 (Baby Talk)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0641741/) (18 Oct. 1960), [Maynard G. Krebs](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001134/) says

> Good thinking

but without any name (from [IMBd.com list of quotes of Maynard G. Krebs](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0047955/quotes)).

I have not found an occurrence of *"Good Thinking + Name"*

---

Australia

The only australian refereces I found was in the [bookcrosing.com](http://www.bookcrossing.com/forum/8/177989/2338924) forum:

> Good thinking 99 - Greetings from NSW Australia
>   -- [Glenasena](http://www.bookcrossing.com/mybookshelf/Glenasena/) - Jun 26 '06

(NSW meaning New South Wales)

Comment: No, no, no. *"Good thinking, Robin!"* came **after** "*Good thinking, Batman!*". I want to know when the *Batman!* appellative was first said. It has to be before 7/12/66.

Comment: Sorry, about the misunderstanding... I just searched through the scripts, and can't find the quote, but a few were missing, so I will keep searching and edit in when I find it.

Comment: Edited, may help?

Answer (score 1):

I just used good thinking 99 in Australia when texting my husband. I’ve always thought it was from Get Smart which played a lot here when I was a child.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).